# delete post method not working with noticed gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications, rubygems, comments

i have simple module inquest with comments , I used noticed gem to add notifications to comments , but when I delete inquest post , it stops server with page not working , and delete the whole account , like I can't login with that account again.i'm new with this gem.
inquest.rb

```
class Inquest < ApplicationRecord
acts_as_votable
belongs_to :user,  dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments, -> {order(:created_at => :desc)}, dependent: :destroy
has_many_attached :images 
validates :description, presence: true
has_noticed_notifications model_name: 'Notification'
has_many :notifications, through: :user, dependent: :destroy
validates :title, :presence => true, :length => { 
    :maximum => 250,
    :minimum => 25,
    :tokenizer => lambda { |str| str.scan(/\w+/) },
    :too_long  => "Please limit your summary to %{count} words"
  }

  end
```

notification.rb

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
 include Noticed::Model
  belongs_to :recipient, polymorphic: true 
 end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :inquest 
belongs_to :user
validates :content, presence: true

  after_create_commit :notify_recipient
 before_destroy :cleanup_notifications
 has_noticed_notifications model_name: 'Notification' 

 private

 def notify_recipient
Commentnotification.with(comment: self, inquest: inquest).deliver_later(inquest.user)
 end

 def cleanup_notifications
   notifications_as_comment.destroy_all
 end
 end
```

user.rb

```
   has_many :notifications, as: :recipient
```

commentnotification.rb

```
  def message
@inquest = Inquest.find(params[:comment][:inquest_id])
@comment = Comment.find(params[:comment][:id])
@user = User.find(@comment.user_id)
"#{@user.user_name} commented on #{@inquest.title.truncate(10)}"

 end
 def URL
    inquest_path(Inquest.find(params[:comment][:inquest_id]))
 end
```

Comment: Why are you deleting the user with `Inquest`? Your association says: `belongs_to :user,  dependent: :destroy` which is probably deleting the user and that is why you are unable to log in again. A `User` might have multiple `Inquest` and not just one I assume.

Comment: yes , it worked , i didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you have `dependent: :destroy` in your association:

```
class Inquest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
end
```

which deletes the user with `Inquest` so the account is deleted. A `User` can have many `Inquest` and there are many related associations usually with `User` so destroying it with other objects is a bad idea. Instead, the `User` model should have `dependent: :destroy` with the associations in general cases.